# gpg-agent on start up without open session

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, password-store

**Environment**

Ubuntu Server 18.04

gpg2 v2.2.4

pass v1.7.1

**Question**

Is there a way to start gpg-agent **--supervised** on startup ? When I try to start `gpg-agent --supervised`, I get :

```
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.2.4 starting in supervised mode.
no LISTEN_PID environment variable found in --supervised mode (ignoring)
no LISTEN_FDS or LISTEN_FDNAMES environment variables found in --supervised mode (assuming 1 active descriptor)
Fatal: file descriptor 3 must be valid in --supervised mode if LISTEN_FDNAMES is not set
```

**Details**

I'm trying to install protonmail-bridge & postfix on my ubuntu server. Protonmail-bridge require gnome-keyring or pass in order to start. I don't know why, but gnome-keyring doesn't work on server (works fine on my laptop with linux mint). I can start bridge with pass. In order to `pass init`, I need gpg2 key.

Everything works fine when I do it manually, I can send mails. Let's script it to run automatically on reboot (through @reboot in cron). I need to cache gpg2 key's passphrase with gpg-agent.

```
#!/bin/bash
KEYID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PIDOF=`pidof gpg-agent`
RETVAL=$?

# Start gpg-agent if it's not running
if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 1 ]; then 
  eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
fi

# Cache passphrase
echo "my_passphrase" | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -v -c $KEYID

# Start bridge
protonmail-bridge --noninteractive &
```

This script isn't working as long as I don't log in. I edited script like that to discover it :

```
#!/bin/bash
KEYID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PIDOF=`pidof gpg-agent`
RETVAL=$?

# Start gpg-agent if it's not running
if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 1 ]; then 
  eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
fi

# Show running gpg-agents
ps aux | grep gpg-agent > protonmail.log
echo " " >> protonmail.log
COUNT=`pidof gpg-agent | wc -w`
# While gpg-agent --daemon is the only one
while [ "$COUNT" -lt 2 ]; do
  sleep 10
  # Trying strat gpg-agent --supervised and caching passphrase
  echo "my_passphrase" | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -v -c $KEYID
  COUNT=`pidof gpg-agent | wc -w`
  # Show running gpg-agents
  ps aux | grep gpg-agent >> protonmail.log
  echo " " >> protonmail.log
done

# Cache passphrase
echo "my_passphrase" | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -v -c $KEYID

# Start bridge
protonmail-bridge --noninteractive &
```

With these logs, I can see that `gpg-agent --homedir /home/myaccount/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon` is running from the beginning of the script, and `/usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised` starts as soon as I'm log in. When supervised mode is running, passphrase caching and bridge is working. But, I can't log to servers on each reboot...

I tried to export lot of environment variables unsuccessful.

Edit:

**Workaround**

After modifying /usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent.service, gpg-agent --supervised failed (yeah, I don't know how to edit services...). gpg keep working in `ps aux`, but not as supervised mode :

```
gpg-agent --homedir /home/my_account/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
```

I think the important param is *--use-standard-socket* (I'm sure I tested it before...).

Anyway, editing my first script like following (and adding some exports), passphrase is cached as I wanted to :

```
#!/bin/bash
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY

KEYID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PIDOF=`pidof gpg-agent`
RETVAL=$?

# Start gpg-agent if it's not running
if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 1 ]; then 
  if [ -f "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then
    . "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
    export GPG_AGENT_INFO
  fi
  eval $(gpg-agent --homedir /home/my_account/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon)
fi

# Cache passphrase
echo "my_passphrase" | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -v -c $KEYID

# Start bridge
protonmail-bridge --noninteractive &
```

Comment: Do you still need this solution? I know how to create the service file and run in --supervised. The use-standard-socket is a very old option

Comment: I didn't modify it from 2020. So sure, I'm interested by your knowledge :)